# Is it possible to get the Horadric cube with a level lower than 70?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to get the cube right at the start of a season journey with level 10 for example?

Comment: I don't have any proof so just a comment...   I used to get it pretty early on every new season with no issues (and would extract the legendary powers of low level legendary items).  So unless they have changed something in in the past few seasons I believe you can.  I haven't played for a few seasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is no level requirement for getting the cube. Just start in Adventure Mode and go get it!

Comment: I believe you have to have completed the campaign at least once on the account to unlock adventure mode, but you only have to do that once, not per-season.

Comment: @MooingDuck what you said used to be true but not anymore: you can now go in adventure mode from the start. Source: I just bought Diablo 3 for Switch and levelled to Paragon 200 exclusively in adventure mode.